# live stream button is now showing

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8, laravel-9, live-streaming

For Live Video streaming, I am following this tutorial https://dev.to/mupati/live-stream-with-webrtc-in-your-laravel-application-2kl3

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/streaming', [WebrtcStreamingController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/streaming/{streamId}', [WebrtcStreamingController::class, 'consumer']);
Route::post('/stream-offer', [WebrtcStreamingController::class, 'makeStreamOffer']);
Route::post('/stream-answer', [WebrtcStreamingController::class, 'makeStreamAnswer']);
```

In resources/js/app.js

```
import Broadcaster from './components/Broadcaster.vue';

// Register the Broadcaster component
Vue.component('broadcaster', Broadcaster);

// Streaming Components
Vue.component("broadcaster", require("./components/Broadcaster.vue").default);
Vue.component("viewer", require("./components/Viewer.vue").default);

const app = createApp({
    // Your application configuration
});

import './bootstrap';
```

In resources/views/video-broadcast.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.publichome')


@section('admin_content')
    @if ($type === 'broadcaster')
        <broadcaster
        :auth_user_id="{{ $id }}"
        env="{{ env('APP_ENV') }}"
        turn_url="{{ env('TURN_SERVER_URL') }}"
        turn_username="{{ env('TURN_SERVER_USERNAME') }}"
        turn_credential="{{ env('TURN_SERVER_CREDENTIAL') }}"
        />
    @else
        <viewer stream_id="{{ $streamId }}" :auth_user_id="{{ $id }}" turn_url="{{ env('TURN_SERVER_URL') }}"
            turn_username="{{ env('TURN_SERVER_USERNAME') }}" turn_credential="{{ env('TURN_SERVER_CREDENTIAL') }}" />
    @endif
@endsection
```

This is my .env
according to https://webrtc.org/getting-started/turn-server
[See the values in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPa64.png)

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:7oMdl/D+p/6YmE7yz2gK5uoqj0uRLZw+vp4Nt09IC9s=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=local

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cricbang
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER="smtp"
MAIL_HOST="sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io"
MAIL_PORT="2525"
MAIL_USERNAME="11ec72dc7d74dd"
MAIL_PASSWORD="c6342b48044ad8"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION="tls"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="sales@onesttech.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="KhelarAdda"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

NOCAPTCHA_SITEKEY=6Lfn6nQhAAAAAKYauxvLddLtcqSn1yqn-HRn_CbN
NOCAPTCHA_SECRET=6Lfn6nQhAAAAABOzRtEjhZYB49Dd4orv41thfh02

BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=1578668
PUSHER_APP_KEY=08cac8944fc51f10a17d
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=5adc5b02e9a7583725fd
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=ap2


TURN_SERVER_URL='turn:my-turn-server.mycompany.com:19403'
TURN_SERVER_USERNAME='optional-username'
TURN_SERVER_CREDENTIAL='auth-token'
```

In my resources/views/video-broadcast.blade.php
if I @dd($type) I got value broadcaster
[See debug result in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGeRd.png)
But my start strimming button is not visible What just I miss? Thank you!

Note:- I am a beginner on laravel